# Auto-scroll items in navbar according to active section

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navbar, nav

Can anyone tell me how to make categories navbar like from delivery-club app?

Here is what i have already, you can check it by this link - http://testingsite.tmweb.ru/delivery/

But i can't make autoscroll items in navbar when we scroll from section to section.
I see that new web apps use front-end frameworks but i not good at it yet so i use Jquery.
I tried some stuff but it doesn't work. So some code for you guys as well, hope you can help me.

Html

```
!-- category navigation -->
<div class="catnav_wrap">
   <nav class="catnav" data-toggle="sticky-onscroll">
      <span role="button" class="catnav_item" data-scroll="pizza">
       pizza
       </span>
       <span role="button" class="catnav_item" data-scroll="burgers">
       burger
       </span>
       <span role="button" class="catnav_item" data-scroll="salats">
       салаты
       </span>
       <span role="button" class="catnav_item" data-scroll="drinks">
       Напитки
       </span>
       <span role="button" class="catnav_item" data-scroll="souce">
       Соуса
       </span>
       <span role="button" class="catnav_item">
       Другое
       </span>
       <span role="button" class="catnav_item">
       Пицца
       </span>
   </nav>
</div>
<!-- category navigation -->
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.catnav span').on('click', function() {
var scrollAnchor = $(this).attr('data-scroll'),
    scrollPoint = $('section[data-anchor="' + scrollAnchor + '"]').offset().top - 70;
$('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: scrollPoint
}, 500);
return false;})

// Custom function which toggles between sticky class (is-sticky)
            var stickyToggle = function (sticky, stickyWrapper, scrollElement) {
                var stickyHeight = sticky.outerHeight();
                var stickyTop = stickyWrapper.offset().top;
                if (scrollElement.scrollTop() >= stickyTop) {
                    stickyWrapper.height(stickyHeight);
                    sticky.addClass("fixed");
                }
                else {
                    sticky.removeClass("fixed");
                    stickyWrapper.height('auto');
                }
            };
            // Find all data-toggle="sticky-onscroll" elements
            $('[data-toggle="sticky-onscroll"]').each(function () {
                var sticky = $(this);
                var stickyWrapper = $('<div>').addClass('sticky-wrapper'); // insert hidden element to maintain actual top offset on page
                sticky.before(stickyWrapper);
                sticky.addClass('fixed');

                // Scroll & resize events
                $(window).on('scroll.sticky-onscroll resize.sticky-onscroll', function () {
                    stickyToggle(sticky, stickyWrapper, $(this));
                });

                // On page load
                stickyToggle(sticky, stickyWrapper, $(window));
            });

$(window).scroll(function() {
var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
if (windscroll >= 0) {
    $('.main .productscat').each(function(i) {
        if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll - -80) {
            $('.catnav span.active').removeClass('active');
            $('.catnav span').eq(i).addClass('active');
        }
    });
} else {
    $('.catnav span.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.catnav span:first').addClass('active');
}
}).scroll();

});//Jquery
```

Css

```
/*category nav*/  
   
.catnav_wrap{
height: 56px;
width: 100%;
   }
.catnav{
height: 56px;
width: 100%;
overflow-x: auto;
background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
display: flex !important;
-webkit-box-align: center;
align-items: center;
top: 0px;
z-index: 99;
will-change: box-shadow;
transition: box-shadow 150ms ease 0s;
user-select: none;
   }
.catnav::before, .catnav::after {
content: " ";
display: block;
width: 12px;
height: 56px;
flex: 0 0 auto;
}
.fixed {
position: fixed;
box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 10%) 0px 2px 4px 0px;
   }
.catnav_item{
display: block;
margin: 4px;
height: 32px;
color: rgb(69, 75, 84);
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 32px;
padding: 0px 16px;
border-radius: 16px;
flex: 0 0 auto;
opacity: 0.6;
transition-property: opacity;
transition-duration: 200ms;
   }     
.catnav_item.active {
margin: 4px;
height: 32px;
background: rgb(243, 243, 247);
/*background: rgb(255, 240, 230);
color: rgb(186, 78, 0);*/
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 32px;
padding: 0px 16px;
border-radius: 16px;
flex: 0 0 auto;
opacity: 1;
  }
/*end category nav*/
```

Comment: Why don't you give your sections ids (`id="pizza"`, `id="burger"`), and then use links (`#pizza`, `#burger` etc) instead of those spans to jump to the correct section? It would probably save you a lot of time and code.

Comment: try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView and also I agree with @Andy id would be better option but if you want smooth behavior then use mix of `scrollIntoView` and `id` attrib of sections.

Comment: @Andy you might get my question wrong. I need my navbar items to be automatically horizontal scrolled when i go through sections just like delivery-club app does.